# How to filter characters from a string in Swift 4

Tags: swift, string

In the following Swift 3 code I'm extracting all numbers from a string but I can not figure out how to do the same thing in Swift 4.

```
var myString = "ABC26FS464"

let myNumbers = String(myString.characters.filter { "01234567890".characters.contains($0)})

print(myNumbers) // outputs 26464
```

How can I extract all numbers from a string in Swift 4?

Comment: Exactly the same code works in Swift 4 as well (with a "characters is deprecated" warning)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Swift 4 makes it a little simpler. Just remove the .characters and use

```
let myNumbers = myString.filter { "0123456789".contains($0) }
```

But to really do it properly, you might use the decimalDigits character set...

```
let digitSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
let myNumbers = String(myString.unicodeScalars.filter { digitSet.contains($0) })
```

Comment: @ 85Camaro What is the difference?

Comment: @fs_tigre, it is the same outcome

Comment: I know but I was curious to know why the second option is the preferred way.

Comment: Well, other than not having to declare and maintain your own character set (more relevant to other character sets, though you do have two 0's), one could argue that the character set method is localizable.

Comment: @85Camaro btw no need to use a set and/or contains on your second one. you can use range pattern matching  `let numbers = String(myString.unicodeScalars.filter { UnicodeScalar("0")..."9" ~= $0 })`

Comment: Since the filter function takes a function with one parameter, you could just write `String(myString.unicodeScalars.filter(digitSet.contains))`

Answer (score 5):

## Easiest:

As "Character" has almost all the most used character checking with ".isXY" computed properties, you can use this pattern, which seems to be the most convenient and Swifty way to do string filtering.

```
/// Line by line explanation.
let str = "Stri1ng wi2th 3numb4ers".filter(\.isNumber) // "1234"
let int = Int(str)                                     // Optional<Int>(1234)
let unwrappedInt = int!                                // 1234

/// Solution.
extension String {

    /// Numbers in the string as Int.
    /// 
    /// If doesn't have any numbers, then 0.
    var numbers: Int {
        Int(filter(\.isNumber)) ?? 0
    }

    /// Numbers in the string as Int.
    ///
    /// If doesn't have any numbers, then nil.
    var optionalNumbers: Int? {
        Int(filter(\.isNumber))
    }
}
```