# How to replace multiple characters in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi guys I have a problem with replacingOccurences, couldn't get more than one character. I tried this code but it didn't work. When i enter the this text = "aaba kouq bux" if repTime[c] = 2 I want to delete a,b,u, then get this text = "koq x"

```
func removeString(text:String, repTime : Int)-> String{
    
 var repTime = [Character: Int]()

 for c in text {
    
     if let count = repTime[c] {
         repTime[c] = count + 1
     } else {
         repTime[c] = 1
     }
    
    if repTime[c] == 2{
    let textA = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "[ a|\\b|\\u]", with: "",options: [.regularExpression])
    return textA
    }
 }
return text
}
```

Comment: Instead of just showing code that isn't doing what you want it to do, **describe** what you're trying to do.

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to do... Do you want to take any string, and remove all occurrences of any character that appears more than once? So, if you have "ab ac" you want a result of "b c"? But, **your** example of "***aaba kouq bux***" you only want to remove **ONE** of the spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `replacingOccurrences` means that you would like to replace occurrences of string within string. So basically you would use it to replace all occurrences of "dog" with "cat". It means that "I have a dog. My dog is very neat..." would be converted to "I have a cat. My cat is very neat...".

From what your seem to try to do is to actually filter out some of the characters. You could try an answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232531/526828). With some small tweaks you should probably get something like

```
let textA = text.filter { "[ a|\\b|\\u]".contains($0) == false }
```

So basically you would like to have a same text but removing all characters that are contained within the string `"[ a|\\b|\\u]"`.

Comment: Thank you so much but when I tried to this code, it remove the right characters but it merge the other character i mean it is show like this ; "koqx" but it should be like this "koq x"

Comment: @semihözsoy because space " " is part of your string as well. So it might be that you need "[a|\\b|\\u]" instead of "[ a|\\b|\\u]"?

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much